# Can we use multiple variables in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Can we use multiple variables in foreach

```
foreach (var item1 in collection1;var items2 in collection2)
{

}
```

I want to do this because I need to fetch two collections from a database and append both of them to a ComboBox.

Comment: Care to describe in more detail how you'd expect this to work?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I have two collection where i like to append two result for the combobox

Comment: What I mean is, how would you expect this construct to actually function? Given your sample code above, and assuming that `collection1` and `collection2` are of different lengths, what would you want this to actually do?

Comment: I don't know who reduce the mark...............

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking about a detailed (incorrect) solution, rather than about the actual issue you're facing. Please state the *intention* of what you want to do.

Comment: @J.Steen I like to fetch the two collection and append them

Comment: How would you append *one* collection to your combobox?

Comment: @J.Steen I meant to append two collection into one combobox

Comment: Yes, and my point was: How would you append the first one? Use that knowledge, and try to apply it to the second one. Or just read lc.'s answer below.

Comment: @J.Steen I am referring that I am trying it out

Comment: Appending is a sequential operation and doesn't require something like this: 1)append collection 1 to X -> 2)append collection 2 to X after collection 1 -> ... -> N)append collection N to X after collection N-1. Example: Hashtable.Add()

Suggestion:if you still insist on doing something like this you can see how many elements you have in there by calling "Count" and replace the foreach- with a for-loop (with multiple counters if you want to do something parallel).Even in a case of a standard for-loop you will rarely see something like:

for(int i=..., j=...; ... ; i+=..., j+=...) { }

Answer (score 16):

Use LINQ to join the arrays putting the result into an anonymous type, then iterate over the resulting collection.

```
var col = collection1.Join(collection2, x => x, y => y, (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y });
foreach (var entry in col) {
    // entry.X, entry.Y
}
```

**Edit:**

When posting the answer I assumed that `collection1` and `collection2` contained different types. If they contain both the same type or share a common base type, there are alternatives:

If you want to allow duplicates:

```
collection1.Concat(collection2); // same type
collection1.select(x => (baseType)x).Concat(collection2.select(x => (baseType)x)); // shared base type
```

No duplicates:

```
collection1.Union(collection2); // same type
collection1.select(x => (baseType)x).Union(collection2.select(x => (baseType)x)); // shared base type
```

Form framework 4.0 onwards Zip can replace the original solution:

```
collection1.Zip(collection2, (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y });
```

For an overview over most of the available LINQ funktions please refer to [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Without LINQ use two hierarchical foreach loops (increasing the number of interations) or one foreach loop to create an inermediate type and a second to iterate over the collection of intermediates or if the types in the collections are the same add them to a list (using `AddRange)` and then iterate over this new list.

Many roads lead to one goal ... its up to you to chose one.

Comment: I am not getting this result guys

Comment: What result, exactly, are you not getting, Anish? *Be specific.*

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I will get back to you once i try it

Comment: Use Zip instead: `var col = collection1.Zip(collection2, (X, Y) => new {X, Y}); foreach (var entry in col) //...`

Comment: @Anish: Added a mor complete review of the topic.

Answer (score 7):

You can Zip the collections

```
foreach (var item in collection1.Zip(collection2, (a, b) => new {  A = a, B = b }))
{
  var a = item.A;
  var b = item.B;
  // ...
}
```

This assumes that the elements match at the same position (e.g. the first element from collection1 joins the first element of collecion2). It is quite efficient.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use multiple variables in a foreach, in loop. Check the [language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). What would happen if each collection had a different number of items?

If you want to iterate over both collections, try using a union:

```
foreach (var item1 in collection1.Union(collection2))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: What can we do then in php we can use two variables why not in dot net

Comment: @Anish in Visual Basic, we can create exception filters.  Why not in C#?

Comment: @Anish you misinterpret my comment.  Let me rephrase: In the farmer's market, we can buy spinach.  Why not in the bookstore?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your comments I think what you're really trying to do is *not* get the Cartesian product of the two collections, but a [SQL] `UNION` of the two sets. You have two options:

1. `Concat` the two collections:

   ```
   foreach(var items in collection1.Concat(collection2)) {}
   ```
2. Just add them both separately, assuming you don't need to do anything fancy by iterating (probably the best/simplest):

   ```
   myComboBox.Items.AddRange(collection1);
   myComboBox.Items.AddRange(collection2);
   ```

---

If, however, you do want the n*m Cartesian product of [SQL pseudocode] `collection1 CROSS JOIN collection2`, you would use two nested foreach statements:

```
foreach(var item1 in collection1)
foreach(var item2 in collection2)
{
}
```

Or, you can join the two in LINQ and iterate over the joined collection:

```
foreach(var items in (from i1 in collection1 
                      from i2 in collection2 
                      select Tuple.Create(i1, i2)))
{
}
```

Comment: From the comments provided, it would seem that example 2, the small, two-line example of code, would be the best bet at an appropriate, uncomplicated, working answer. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Agreed. I didn't see the new comments. Edited and reordered my answer. (Thanks for your comment edit as well :))

Comment: @lc. You kept me on my toes! =)

Comment: @Ic. System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' this error is shown

Comment: @Anish Did you forget a `using System.Linq;`?

Answer (score 1):

foreach is used to enumerate individual items in a collection. So no you can't. You have to use it one after the other.
It would be better to use:

```
void myfunc()
{}

foreach(var item1 in collection1){myfunc();}
foreach(var item2 in collection2){myfunc();}
```

than

```
foreach(var item1 in collection1)
foreach(var item2 in collection2)
{
    myfunc();
}
```

This would run for n*m times. Whereas previous example would run for only n+m times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a newer syntax:

```
    var collection1 = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
    var collection2 = new List<int>(){5,6,7,8};
    
    var zip = collection1.Zip(collection2, (i,j) => (i,j));
    
    foreach (var (item1, item2) in zip)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"item1:{item1} item2:{item2}");
    }

    // outputs:
    //item1:1 item2:5
    //item1:2 item2:6
    //item1:3 item2:7
    //item1:4 item2:8
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pair the items from one collection with corresponding items of the other?

```
foreach (var pair in col1.Zip(col2, (Item1, Item2) => new { Item1, Item2 })
{
    //do something with pair.Item1 and pair.Item2
}
```

Note: if the first collection has 10 items and the second has 8, you will get 8 pairs; the last two items in the first collection will be dropped because there's nothing to match them with in the second collection.  More generally, the number of iterations will be `Min(col1.Count(), col2.Count())`.

Do you want to iterate all of the items in one collection and then all of the items in the second?

```
foreach (var element in col1.Concat(col2))
{
    //do something with element
}
```

Note: if the first collection has 10 elements and the second has 8, this loop will execute 18 times, or, more generally, the number of iterations will be `col1.Count() + col2.Count()`.

Do you want to pair each item in one collection with each item in the other?

```
foreach (var item1 in col1)
    foreach (var item2 in col2)
    {
         //do something with item1 and item2
    }
```

Note: this is the cartesian product, so, not surprisingly, the number of iterations is the product of the collections' sizes.  If we have 10 and 8 items, the loop will execute 80 times.  For consistency's sake, that's `col1.Count() * col2.Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterator:

```
IEnumerator <Item2Type> item2Itt = Collection2.GetEnumerator();
item2Itt.MoveNext(); // The iterator returned above is BEFORE the first element in the collection.
foreach (Item1Type item1 in collection1)
{
    item1.blahblahblah;
    item2Itt.Current.blahBlahBlah;
    item2Itt.MoveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way can be used:

```
List<Type> allOfThem = new List<Type>(); //use proper type for collection
allOfThem.AddRange(collection1);
allOfThem.AddRange(collection2);

foreach (Type item in allOfThem)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using enumerator is the simplest way to do it. You can use either of the two collection to get the enumerator and run foreach on the other one.

```
    public void MatchSentences() {
                string[] OrigSentences = { "hello you", "what are you doing", "hope things are fine" };
                string[] CompareSentences = { "hello you", "what are you doing", "hope things are fine" };
                // Get enumerator on the second collection
                var outputStrEnum = CompareSentences.GetEnumerator();
    
                // Run foreach on the first collection
                foreach (var sentence in OrigSentences) {
                    outputStrEnum.MoveNext();
                    string testAgainst = outputStrEnum.Current.ToString();
                    bool result = sentence.Equals(testAgainst);
                    
                    Assert.IsTrue(result,
                        String.Format(" Expected for '{0}': {1}; Actual: '{2}'",
                                testAgainst, result,sentence) );
                }
    
            }
```